# Merging three different rasters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, vector

I am doing multi-classification using the raster.

I rasterized vectors (farmlands, buildings, and forests) with 1,2,3 raster values, respectively. I have 3 rasters and I want to merge them. I tried with the merge tool in QGIS, but that gives the raster value in range 0-3 and there is no 1 and 2.

How can I merge them into one?

I tried to put values into the separate bands, but that returned only a black raster.

I need to create such a mask layer.

[image]

Comment: Did you set up the right field for the burn-in value in the rasterize tool ? Do the three rasters share the same resolution ?
I just gave a try and didn't encounter any issue with the merge tool.
Are you sure you can't get the "2" raster values by mean of the Identify tool ?